# Azure Mobile Service with Xamarin

Tags: azure

I'm new to all this.

When creating a mobile service on Azure and selected a DB.
How do you the the mobile service code that you download to include the data objects in the DB?  I just get the TODOITEMs.
How do you used the EF with Azure and Mobile services to generate the service?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out this tutorial on MSDN Blogs, by Carlos Figueira from the Azure Mobile Services team.

**Creating an Azure Mobile Services .NET backend from scratch**

- http://blogs.msdn.com/b/azuremobile/archive/2014/04/10/creating-an-azure-mobile-services-net-backend-from-scratch.aspx

There is a question below the article that asks whether this .NET back-end will work with Xamarin as well, to which the author responds: "Yes it should work with Xamarin as well"

Hope that helps!